# Use text that is passed through props, to know which constant is called for button onClick

Tags: javascript, reactjs

does anyone know how I can pass the name of the const I want to use for the button onClick here?

So I have two const's defined in my component, what I want to achieve is that each button in a column calls a different const, so I pass the name of the const I want to use through props, but that doesn't work. For example if I pass `clickHandler="handleFirstOption"`

The column button onClick has to become:

```
<Button role="group" mt={10} onClick={handleFirstOption}>
```

Does anyone know how I can accomplish this?

**FooterRow.jsx**

```
<FooterColumn
   clickHandler="handleFirstOption"
/>
<FooterColumn
   clickHandler="handleSecondOption"
/>
```

**FooterColumn.jsx**

```
const handleFirstOption = event => {
   updateStep(firstOption);
};

const handleSecondOption = event => {
   updateStep(secondOption);
   event.preventDefault();
};
```

```
<Button role="group" mt={10} onClick={clickHandler}>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define this inside your `FooterColumn`:

```
let handlers = {

    handleFirstOption: event => {
        updateStep(firstOption);
    }
    handleSecondOption: event => {
        updateStep(secondOption);
        event.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

Then you can specify which handler you want using string name from props:

```
<Button role="group" mt={10} onClick={handlers[clickHandler]}>
```

Comment: I can't, because handleFirstOption is only defined in the component where the button is in

Comment: @Mauro Check the updated answer

Comment: Oh thank you so much man, this indeed did the job for me! :)